# AWS DMS fails to migrate text columns between RDS Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I have two RDS Postgres clusters in two separate AWS accounts on a set of paired VPCs, they can connect through the task instance just fine.

However, the task fails because of unique constraints. After I removed the constraints I see that the data inserted into my new cluster is missing all text columns data. So in reality it's not grabbing any text or lobs even though I have it set to full mode.

My end goal is really just a 1:1 copy of my rds cluster in my first account with ongoing replication until I switch over. I've turned on default debugging but not seeing any helpful errors.

This error doesn't make any sense to me though since I don't even have an `events` table.

```
2021-11-03T02:53:48:343248 [DATA_STRUCTURE  ]E:  SQLite general error. Code <19>, Message <UNIQUE constraint failed: events.identifier, events.eventType, events.detailMessage>. [1000505]  (at_sqlite.c:525)
```

This is the only other warning that shows up in the logs.

```
2021-11-03T03:06:40:405809 [TASK_MANAGER    ]W:  Table 'public'.'bridge_types' (subtask 1 thread 1) is suspended  (replicationtask.c:2527)
```

Here is my table mapping settings:

```json
{
"rules": [
{
"rule-type": "selection",
"rule-id": "1",
"rule-name": "1",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "%",
"table-name": "bridge_types"
},
"rule-action": "include",
"filters": []
}
]
}
```

Here is my task settings:

```json
{
"Logging": {
"EnableLogging": true,
"LogComponents": [
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
"Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "IO"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
"Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "PERFORMANCE"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
"Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "SORTER"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "REST_SERVER"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
"Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "COMMON"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "ADDONS"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "COMMUNICATION"
},
{
"Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
"Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
}
],
"CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-db-test-replication",
"CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-ASPBCUAYMDE3TMD5HUZTMECM52RBD774RUSRIAA"
},
"StreamBufferSettings": {
"StreamBufferCount": 3,
"CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
"StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
},
"ErrorBehavior": {
"FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
"ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
"RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
"DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
"ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
"RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
"ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
"DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
"DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
"RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
"ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
"TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
"DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
},
"ValidationSettings": {
"ValidationPartialLobSize": 0,
"PartitionSize": 10000,
"RecordFailureDelayLimitInMinutes": 0,
"SkipLobColumns": false,
"FailureMaxCount": 10000,
"HandleCollationDiff": false,
"ValidationQueryCdcDelaySeconds": 0,
"ValidationMode": "ROW_LEVEL",
"TableFailureMaxCount": 1000,
"RecordFailureDelayInMinutes": 5,
"MaxKeyColumnSize": 8096,
"EnableValidation": true,
"ThreadCount": 5,
"RecordSuspendDelayInMinutes": 30,
"ValidationOnly": false
},
"FullLoadSettings": {
"CommitRate": 10000,
"StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
"StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": true,
"MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
"TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
"CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
"TargetTablePrepMode": "DO_NOTHING"
},
"TargetMetadata": {
"ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
"ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
"ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
"TargetSchema": "",
"InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
"ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
"SupportLobs": true,
"LobChunkSize": 4096,
"TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
"ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
"LobMaxSize": 0,
"BatchApplyEnabled": false,
"FullLobMode": true,
"LimitedSizeLobMode": false,
"LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
"ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
},
"BeforeImageSettings": null,
"ControlTablesSettings": {
"historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
"HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
"StatusTableEnabled": false,
"SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
"HistoryTableEnabled": false,
"ControlSchema": "",
"FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
},
"LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
"CharacterSetSettings": null,
"FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
"ChangeProcessingTuning": {
"StatementCacheSize": 50,
"CommitTimeout": 1,
"BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
"BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
"BatchSplitSize": 0,
"BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
"MinTransactionSize": 1000,
"MemoryKeepTime": 60,
"BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
"MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
},
"ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
"HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
"HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
"HandleSourceTableAltered": true
},
"PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

Comment: The only supported transformation for columns that are mapped to BLOB/CLOB data types is to drop the column on the target. [Transformations.Limitation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.Limitation)